# Why there is still error on List view length

Tags: flutter, gridview, google-cloud-firestore

I specified a StreamBuilder which have Gridview.builder as a function under builder of (StreamBuilder) and i specified the stream to Cloud Firestore. I specified the length of GridView.

The list worked and came out but it will be `length was called to null` error for about 2 seconds. The list will still show according to the length of the snapshot but it's still bringing the error.

Please what can I do?

Comment: Hi, Jeremiah! Can you please add a sample of the code so we can help you? Without the code, all I can say is that it's probably missing some verification to check if your list still empty or not. It probably is empty for that first 2 seconds you said, after that it gets some value.

Comment: Please add your code snippet

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because data has not available at the time your build method runs. so, you need to check if data is available then show your Gridview.

See the following code in the builder method you need to check snapshot has data or not also check the connection status ones connection status is done you can show Gridview

```
builder:(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
   if (!snapshot.hasData) {
     return Loader();
   }
   if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
      // Your Gridview should be here
   }

  return Loader();
```